# Android - How To create dynamic alarm/notification from different condition using Realm Object Database?

Tags: android, realm, alarmmanager

i am building a simple app for schedule, i using Realm Database. in realm i saved date for alarm. i have more than 2 object with different date, but same date format.
this is my sample Database :

```
public class type1Activity extends RealmObject{
Date dateType1;
}
public class type2Activity extends RealmObject{
Date dateType2;
}
```

the problem is, how to get earliest date, and i want to create onBackground service for count get earliest date from now.
or i must create 1 database, for save all date? for easiest way to count earliest date?
but how i repeat that count while i have notified earliest date.

anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that you keep `type1Activity` and `type2Activity`. You can get all objects sorted using `findAllSorted()` but then you will have to compare the first objects of the two `RealmResults`. If you combine them, you can do a single `findAllSorted()`.